# Extension with protocol conformance not detected outside module

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I have the following code in a module X:

```
protocol A {

}

extension B : A {

}
```

In module Y, I have:

```
func foo() -> A {
  return B()
}
```

I import module X in Y, but when compiling I have an error saying that value of type B cannot be converted to result type A. Well, it should be able to do so, since B conforms to A, as specified in the first file.

Comment: Swift does not allow that for extensions that have protocol conformance

Answer (score 0):

You should add `public` eg:

```
public protocol A {

}

extension B : A {

}
```

Comment: Done that, same complaining from compiler

Comment: Well I had no errors, i assumed that B was a concrete type though

Comment: What if B is an Objective-C @interface

Comment: That does not change anything, I could get an error writing `let b:B = foo()` but it was `Cannot convert value of type 'A' to specified type 'B'` and you're reporting the opposite.

Comment: You got the error in your `foo` function declaration or when you tried calling it ? And where did you declare you class ?